# Passing data form view to controller guzzle Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle6

I try to use guzzle when sending data with fire, always appear resulted in a

> 500 Internal Server Error

Here's the code I'm executing:

**View**

```
<form action="{{URL(route('coba.index'))}}" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col m6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <label for="promoname">Promo Name</label>
                    <input id="promoname" name="promoName" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <label for="promocode">Promo Code</label>
                    <input id="promocode" name="promoCode" type="text">
                </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    class GuzzleController extends Controller
    {
        public function getRemoteData(){            
            $client = new Client;            
            $data = Input::all();
            $promo_name=$data['promoName'];
            $promo_code=$data['promoCode'];

            $url = "http://192.168.0.41:88/API_CmsDeveloop/public/api/v1/price-rules/store";
            $request = $client->post($url, [
                'form_params' => [
                    "promo_name" => $promo_name,
                    "promo_code" => $promo_code
                    ]
            ]);            
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($request );
        }
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/cobaGuzzle','GuzzleController@getRemoteData')->name('coba.index');
```

is there anyone who knows my mistake where??

Comment: It's not enough info, for status code 500 you have to check your server logs to get the real issue. PHP-FPM logs, Laravel logs, etc.

Comment: oh thank you, it helps me

Answer (score 0):

Pass token: `{!! csrf_field() !!}` inside your form. 
And Check. Thanks